# How to reference ambiguous top level variable?

Tags: cobol, disambiguation

In this code, I'd like to `ACCEPT` and `DISPLAY` the 01 level `D` variable. While the 05 level `D` is easy, `D OF F`, is there a way to specify the 01 level `D`?

The obvious solution is “just change the variable name”, but hoping there's a better way!

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
    PROGRAM-ID. DISAMBIGUATION-ISSUE.
DATA DIVISION.
    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 D VALUE PIC 9(8). 
    01 F.
        05 Y PIC 9(4).
        05 M PIC 9(2).
        05 D PIC 9(2).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
*> Errors here, D is ambiguous
    ACCEPT D.
    DISPLAY "Date: " D.
STOP RUN.
```

Comment: **No**, you could introduce a new 01 level (say d-x) and change the `01 D` to `03 D`and do `D of d-x`

Comment: In a nutshell, you can't qualify 01 levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid the only way in this circumstance is to change the variable name or to make the `01`-level `D` into a subordinate item, e.g.

```
 01  D-rec.
     03  D PIC 9(8).
 ...
     DISPLAY D IN D-rec
```